# SQL join conditional either or not both?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have 3 tables that I'm joining and 2 variables that I'm using in one of the joins.

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to join based on either of the statements but not both.

Here's the current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
WR.Id,
CAL.Id as 'CalendarId',
T.[First Of Month],
T.[Last of Month],
WR.Supervisor,
WR.cd_Manager as [Manager], --Added to search by the Manager--
WR.[Shift] as 'ShiftId'
INTO #Workers
FROM #T T

--Calendar
RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[Calendar] CAL
ON  CAL.StartDate <= T.[Last of Month]
AND CAL.EndDate >= T.[First of Month]

--Workers
--This is the problem join
RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[Worker_Filtered]WR
ON WR.Supervisor  IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullName IN(@Supervisors))
or (WR.Supervisor  IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullName IN(@Supervisors))
    AND WR.cd_Manager IN(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullNameIN(@Manager)))   --Added to search by the Manager--
AND WR.[Type] = '333E7907-EB80-4021-8CDB-5380F0EC89FF' --internal

WHERE CAL.Id = WR.Calendar
AND WR.[Shift] IS NOT NULL
```

What I want to do is either have the result based on the `Worker_Filtered` table matching the `@Supervisor` or (but not both) have it matching both the `@Supervisor` and `@Manager`.

The way it is now if it matches either condition it will be returned. This should be limiting the returned results to Workers that have both the Supervisor and Manager which would be a smaller data set than if they only match the Supervisor.

**UPDATE**

The query that I have above is part of a greater whole that pulls data for a supervisor's workers.

I want to also limit it to managers that are under a particular supervisor.

For example, if `@Supervisor = John Doe` and `@Manager = Jane Doe` and `John` has 9 workers 8 of which are under `Jane`'s management then I would expect the end result to show that there are only 8 workers for each month. With the current query, it is still showing all 9 for each month.

If I change part of the `RIGHT JOIN` to:

```
WR.Supervisor  IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullName IN (@Supervisors)) 
    AND WR.cd_Manager IN(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullName IN(@Manager))
```

Then it just returns 12 rows of `NULL`.

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry, this has taken so long to get a sample up. I could not get SQL Fiddle to work for SQL Server 2008/2014 so I am using rextester instead:

[Sample](http://rextester.com/BYQYNG89240)

This shows the results as 108 lines. But what I want to show is just the first 96 lines.

**UPDATE 3**

I have made a slight update to the [Sample](http://rextester.com/YPH40269). this does get the results that I want. I can set `@Manager` to `NULL` and it will pull all 108 records, or I can have the correct Manager name in there and it'll only pull those that match both Supervisor and Manager.

However, I'm doing this with an `IF ELSE` and I was hoping to avoid doing that as it duplicates code for the insert into the Worker table.

Comment: it might be useful to simplify your question and produce a small dataset that shows the problem and what your desired output would be given that dataset with different variable values.

Comment: Just try tweaking this part of code `RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[Worker_Filtered]WR
ON WR.Supervisor  IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullName IN 
(@Supervisors) AND FullName NOT IN (@Manager))`

Comment: @Joby I have tried tweaking it. I've tried without the `OR` I've tried removing the `()` and just having the `OR/AND FullName NOT IN(@Manager)` so far nothing has worked.

Comment: @Tanner This is just one part of the whole query. The end result shows how many workers for the Supervisor for each month of the year. Then the hours worked and a bunch of other data. This part of the query is only pulling in `uniqueidentifier` type data that is then used to get the rest of the numbers. The end result should have 12 rows, 1 for each month. I'll try to get some example data up there that will make sense.

Comment: I think that having `CAL.Id = WR.Calendar` in the `WHERE` clause is effectively turning your `RIGHT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Could this be the source of your problem? And yes, sample data with expected output would be very helpful.

Comment: @Skippy I cannot give you direct samples of the data, But I'll try to come up with something that will work. As for the `WHERE` clause, would putting that into the `RIGHT JOIN` keep it from interfering?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know. Without seeing your table structures and sample data I'm just guessing at possible causes for your problem. I'm also having real trouble getting my head around that second `RIGHT JOIN` and the fact that it doesn't reference either of the other tables in the `ON` part. I'm also having trouble with your "What I want to do..." statement, but I'm sure that once you've come up with your sample data and expected results then all will become clear.

Comment: Mike - your joins seem to imply that it will hit both conditions. I fail to see how you expect to have an exclusive OR going on here. You check for wr.supervisor in... both in the first join and in the first part of the OR join: 
`ON WR.Supervisor  IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullName IN(@Supervisors))
or (WR.Supervisor  IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullName IN(@Supervisors))
    AND WR.cd_Manager IN(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE FullNameIN(@Manager)))`

Comment: @Skippy I have finally gotten a sample together. Hopefully, it will shed some light on what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Eli I know that currently my `joins` will both be hit. that's what I'm needing help with. I want to only have one or the other hit. Either it matches  the supervisor `or` it matches the supervisor and the manager (so that if there is no manager or it doesn't match the given manager it doesn't get pulled)

Comment: @Mike I looked at your sample, and I read your 2 updates. Based on my understanding of your question, it seems as if you want to replace your RIGHT JOIN on WR with the following:
`RIGHT JOIN Worker_Filtered wr on (wr.Supervisor in(@Supervisors) and wr.Manager in(@Manager))   `
This will pull only those which match both. If you want to pull those without a manager, you can set the value of @manager to NULL and it will pull just those 12 records.
Let me know if this works, and I'll post it as the answer

Comment: @Eli that does not work. I have tried that, it returns no results when `@Manager` is `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of expected results in update 3 makes it all clear now, thanks. Your 'problem' join needs to be:

```
RIGHT JOIN Worker_Filtered wr on (wr.Supervisor in(@Supervisors) 
    and case when @Manager is null then 1
             else case when wr.Manager in(@Manager) then 1 else 0 end
             end = 1)
```

By the way, I don't know what you are expecting the `in(@Supervisors)` to achieve, but if you're hoping to supply a comma separated list of supervisors as a single string and have `wr.Supervisor` match any one of them then you're going to be disappointed. This query works exactly the same if you have `= @Supervisors` instead.

Comment: That's it! It works! Oddly enough the `in(@Supervisors)` works as well when it's a comma separated list. I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: Glad that helped. The `in(@Supervisors)` didn't work for me, but if it's working for you then that's a bonus!

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014, don't know if that makes any difference to you or not.